# Endpoint not found. WCF C#

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, web

I have created a WCF web service and there are some methods written in that service. When i right click on that service and "view in browser" and call service method http://localhost:8265/CRMService.svc/GetPricelist then i get this error. Below is my web.config file. Require help

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>



      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <!--<serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="WCFZKTecoService.Authorization.RestAuthorizationManager, WCFZKTecoService"/>-->
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restfulbehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="Procons.Sodamco.SalesForceWCF.CRMService" behaviorConfiguration="">

        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="restfulbehavior" name="RESTEndpoint" contract="Procons.Sodamco.SalesForceWCF.ICRMService"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <protocolMapping>

      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="1" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: is the service host, if yes then are the configuration in your app & wcf service matching

Comment: I am using this service by adding reference of this service in App project and invoking service methods. It is giving error that no default end point. In app.config of App project, nothing here related to service. 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>

Comment: Service project is separate. I am right clicking on it and viewing in project and invoking service method. It is not invoking method from there also and giving error of Endpoint not found

Comment: Did you watch out for http / https differences?

Comment: Is the service on the same box as the app calling it?  If not, the `localhost` address could be the issue.